# Is there a way I can change a ckEditor config without having many almost the same config files?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

In my code I have something like this:

```
var ckeditor = CKEDITOR.replace('mydiv');

var ckeditor = CKEDITOR.replace('mydiv', { customConfig: 'generic-config.js' });
```

Once the instance of ckeditor has been created then is it possible for me to change something. For example can I set these after the instance of the editor has been created?

```
config.entities = false;
config.basicEntities = false;
```

The reason I am asking this is because I need to have different configuration files for some of my editor instances. 99% of the files will be the same so I would like to avoid having many different config files with all the same content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case i would suggest you group them by classes and then use jQuery adapter. You'll be able to group them in readable way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() {
    // 3 diffrent classes, each having diffrent config
    $( '.simpleTextarea' ).ckeditor( { uiColor: '#992222' } ); 
    $( '.advancedTexatrea' ).ckeditor( { uiColor: '#229922' } ); 
    $( 'textarea.blogComment' ).ckeditor( { uiColor: '#222299' } ); 
} );
</script>
<textarea class="simpleTextarea">fooBar2</textarea>
<textarea class="simpleTextarea">fooBar2</textarea>
<textarea class="advancedTexatrea">fooBar2</textarea>
<textarea class="advancedTexatrea">fooBar2</textarea>
<textarea class="blogComment">fooBar2</textarea>
<textarea class="advancedTexatrea">fooBar2</textarea>
```

To use jQuery adapter you need CKEditor at version **4.2** or above.

You can take a look to [jQuery adapter sample](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/13-10-30-07-05/full/samples/jquery.html).